# Download Log Files from Remote Machines Using PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I have a text file containing 200+ remote machine names which are comma delimited.  There are log files on each of these machines which I would like to download to my machine.  In the event that a machine is unreachable (offline), I would like the script to catch the error and write it to a separate failures.log file.

I've read several threads and tried multiple different approaches, but can't seem to get the script to work correctly.  Here's my latest attempt:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\MasterTestGroup.txt"

foreach($item in $csv) {
    try {
        Copy-Item -Path ("\\" + $item + "\c$\Windows\AppLogs\LoginScript_Policy\ClearCredMgrRUN.log") -Destination ("C:\ClearCredMgr_Logs\" + $item + "_ClearCredMgr.log")
    } catch {
        $_ | Out-File "C:\ClearCredMgr_Logs\Failures\failures.log" -Append
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet from the MasterTestGroup.txt file:

486937CPTR,487060CPTR,490028CPTR,499037CPTR,502537CPTR,506342CPTR,507627CPTR,507670CPTR,...

Comment: `Import-Csv` is not suitable for that data format. Use `Get-Content` and split the line at commas.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do not have a proper CSV file. What you are going to want to do is just read it as a text file, and split it on commas. This should do what you want:

```
$rawtext = Get-Content "C:\MasterTestGroup.txt"
$csv = $rawtext -split ','

foreach($item in $csv) {
    try {
        Copy-Item -Path ("\\" + $item + "\c$\Windows\AppLogs\LoginScript_Policy\ClearCredMgrRUN.log") -Destination ("C:\ClearCredMgr_Logs\" + $item + "_ClearCredMgr.log")
    } catch {
        $_ | Out-File "C:\ClearCredMgr_Logs\Failures\failures.log" -Append
    }
}
```